# get the path of a specific field in a graphql query

Tags: python, graphql, strawberry-graphql

I want to get the path of a specific parameter of a graphql query and return it as a list.

for example, there is query like this:

```
query = '''
    query {
        books {
            __typename
            title
        }
        users {
            __typename
            name
            age
        }
    }
'''
```

I need a code in python that returns the path of for example `"__typename"` in list.

like: `[[books, __typename], [users, __typename]]`

can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution context is available in the [Info](https://strawberry.rocks/docs/types/resolvers#accessing-execution-information) object.

```py
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def users(self, info: Info) -> list[User]:
        for field in info.selected_fields:
            print('field', field.name)
            for selection in field.selections:
                print('  selection', selection.name)
        return []
```